# Messaging application using NFT tech?

Tags: ether, nft, message

2 part question.

1. What are some blockchain-based messaging apps? What are their benefits?
2. Could an NFT based messaging app be built? If so what unique properties would it have?

Answer (score 0):

Answering in late 2021:

1. Here is a list of apps that self-advertise as "blockchain based", that I found through Google search:

- [Secretum](https://secretum.io/) - Revolutionary Secure Messaging & Trading dapp on Solana
- [Status](https://status.im/) - Secure messaging app, crypto wallet, and Web3 browser built with state of the art technology.
- [ySign](https://ysign.app/) - Best decentralized messenger based on blockchain technology
- [iMe Messenger](https://imem.app/) - Messenger & Crypto Wallet

2. Some apps mentioned above have plans to implement built-in NFT matketplace.

   For example, iMe Messenger plans to support NFT avatars and neurobots by Jan 2022 on their [roadmap](https://imem.gitbook.io/ime-faq-eng/ime-crypto-wallet/roadmap).

Disclaimer: I'm not affiliated with any apps mentioned above.

You should DYOR to find what's best for you. Those products are in different stages of development, some only have a whitepaper, some have made the product but got very few users, and some already have large user base. Things may change as time passes.